# How can one configure MongoDB sharding using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, sharding

I'm working on setting up a MongoDB replica set on EC2. I'd like to configure auto-sharding such that my nodes can easily come up and down.

Is it possible to use the native PHP driver to trigger sharding and add/remove nodes? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your connection to `mongos` right, you can use the [MongoDB::command()](http://php.net/mongodb.command) method for that:

```
$mongo->selectDB('admin')->command(array('addshard'=>'hostname:port'));
```